# Swiftmailer Multiple SMTP

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

I'm using the PHP Swiftmailer package and was looking for a way to use multiple SMTP servers. I found the Swift LoadBalance Transport and from what I read this would round robin between SMTP connection. However, I have two SMTP servers with each one is running a different mailserver domain. Is there a way to change the  ->setFrom(MAIL_FROM) based on the SMTP server transport instance being used?

Ex. 
$transport1 uses a FROM: company@domain1.com
$transport2 uses a FROM: company@domain2.com

```
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once './config.php';


 // POINT of this sample
$transport1 = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance(SMTP_HOST, SMTP_PORT);
$transport2 = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance(SMTP_HOST2, SMTP_PORT2);
$transport = Swift_LoadBalancedTransport::newInstance([
$transport1,
$transport2,
]);

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
$message
->setFrom(MAIL_FROM)
->setSubject('LoadbalancedTransport sample')
->setBody('This is a mail.');
$recipients = [MAIL_TO, MAIL_TO2];
$total = 0;


foreach ($recipients as $recipient) {
$message->setTo($recipient);
$result = $mailer->send($message);
$total += $result;
}
```

Comment: What you're describing is not load balancing, it's just two separate mail servers, and it's up to you to switch between them.

Comment: And please don't tag as PHPMailer when you're not using it.